# PhpMyAdmin database somehow disappeared

Tags: mysql

Somehow the tables don't appear in phpMyAdmin anymore, but we checked the MySQL data table and the files seem to be there. I could not read them and did not recognize them as any of the available format for import.

At this point, what can I do to import the database with these files? (with extensions MYD .MYI .frm .opt.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHPMyAdmin configuration files could have changed.  I'd check first from logging in from the command line:

mysql -u[USERNAME] -p -h[IPOFHOST], 
so like this:  mysql -uroot -p -hlocalhost (if your server is on localhost).

After logging in, run SHOW DATABASES; you should see your databases, type in USE [DATABASE_NAME]; for the database that you want to inspect, and then type in SHOW TABLES; and then you should see that your tables are still there.